# Wordpress Ajax - returns 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress

always returns 0, I have looked through other answers but nothing help.
Can anybody else help me find a solution?

plugin code:

```
function testOne(){
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "do.php";
}

add_shortcode( 'testOne' , 'testOne' );
```

od.php:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfun', 'myfun' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfun', 'myfun' );

function myfun() {
    echo 'Test';
    wp_die();
}
?>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
              action: "myfun",
          },
          success:function(data){
            alert(data);
          } 
    });
});
</script>
```

header.php in theme:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: i use that code in plugin

Comment: Have you get ajax-url `alert(ajaxurl);`?

Comment: yes
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: ajaxurl,
                  data: {
                            'action':'myfun',
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                });//end ajax
});
</script>
```

Put below ajax function in your theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myfun', 'myfun' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myfun', 'myfun' );

if( !function_exists('myfun') ):
    function myfun(){ 
        echo 'Test';
        exit();
    }
endif;
```

Hope this will Help!

Comment: This code does work on admin pages! (Ankita you need to replace the last } with endif;) I just tried it on my WordPress installation. So, either your installation is seriously broken or the code you are using in the plugin is somehow critically different. My guess is your add_action()'s are not being executed. I would put a breakpoint or an error_log() to verify the add_action()'s are executed. (Ankita, I don't think this will work on non-admin pages as the JavaScript global ajaxurl will not be defined.)

Comment: @user8262086 to get ajax URL this can be done:<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    </script>

Comment: I am suggesting you add that to your code for completeness. If I may further suggest that you wrap your JavaScript code with "add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', .." so the JavaScript code can also be included in the functions.php so everything can just be appended functions.php - makes it easier to test. Anyway, your code works and user3231235's code is somehow critically different.

Comment: yes i added var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code itself rather it is the location of the code that is problem. I would confirm that your add_action() code is really being executed. It would help if you included the code that executes the add_action()'s.

Comment: The AJAX processing is done in two separate calls to the WordPress server. The first call injects the script into the page. The second call processes the AJAX call itself. In the second call testOne() is not called since in AJAX processing no page content is processed and hence no shortcode processing is done.

Comment: In other words, take add_action() and myfun() out of do.php and add it after add_shortcode() and it might work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some issue with ajaxurl variable.

I suggest you to please create a separate javascript file for all code between script tag and than enqueue that script and localize it with ajaxurl.

Below is sample code for localizing :-

```
wp_register_script( 'my-cstm-script', 'script_url_path', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-cstm-script' );

wp_localize_script( 'my-cstm-script', 'MyCstmVar', array( 'ajaxurl'                 => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', ( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' ) ), ) );
```

After this please in php file, which includes on that page, just add your function code and check whether this is working or not.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: So, you need to create javascript files in plugin itself and than do as I suggested.

Comment: Can you just check whether the file, which contains the function, is included or not? You can check this by echoing out something and than exit;

Answer (score 0):

@user3231235 your code is right only write your whole code out of your function which you would declare in plugin.